# How to fix "error: expected comma after load's type"

Tags: llvm

The following instruction doesn't compile:

```
%i = load i32* %p
```

It throws an error:

```
test.ll:27:20: error: expected comma after load's type
    %i = load i32* %p
                   ^
1 error generated.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the [`load`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#load-instruction) instruction was changed in LLVM 3.7. You now need to pass the type of the loaded value, like so:

```
%i = load i32, i32* %p
```